# Customizing a plugin function using a hook

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, hooks

I've written a hook in my functions file that adds a metabox, from an installed plugin, to a custom post type that I've created. The metabox appears fine, but the default selection that is checked in the metabox is "index,follow" whereas I would like it to be "noindex,nofollow" by default. Is there anyway to change the plugins function using my hook?

My hook:

```
    function robotsmeta_add_custom_box() {
        add_meta_box('robotsmeta','Robots Meta',array('RobotsMeta_Admin','noindex_option_fill'),'secured-area','side');
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'robotsmeta_add_custom_box');
```

Plugin's noindex_option_fill function:

```
    function noindex_option_fill() {
        global $post;
        $robotsmeta = $post->robotsmeta;
        if (!isset($robotsmeta) || $robotsmeta == "") {
            $robotsmeta = "index,follow";
        }
        ?>
        <label for="meta_robots_index_follow" class="selectit"><input id="meta_robots_index_follow" name="robotsmeta" type="radio" value="index,follow" <?php if ($robotsmeta == "index,follow") echo 'checked="checked"'?>/> index, follow</label><br/>
        <label for="meta_robots_index_nofollow" class="selectit"><input id="meta_robots_index_nofollow" name="robotsmeta" type="radio" value="index,nofollow" <?php if ($robotsmeta == "index,nofollow") echo 'checked="checked"'?>/> index, nofollow</label><br/>
        <label for="meta_robots_noindex_follow" class="selectit"><input id="meta_robots_noindex_follow" name="robotsmeta" type="radio" value="noindex,follow" <?php if ($robotsmeta == "noindex,follow") echo 'checked="checked"'?>/> noindex, follow</label><br/>
        <label for="meta_robots_noindex_nofollow" class="selectit"><input id="meta_robots_noindex_nofollow" name="robotsmeta" type="radio" value="noindex,nofollow" <?php if ($robotsmeta == "noindex,nofollow") echo 'checked="checked"'?>/> noindex, nofollow</label><br/>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
function set_robotsmeta_default( $post_object ) {
    if (!isset($post_object->robotsmeta) || $post_object->robotsmeta == "") {
        $post_object->robotsmeta = "noindex,nofollow";
    }
    return $post_object;
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'set_robotsmeta_default' );
```

EDIT: Since the above didn't work, the code below may work, by editing the global $post object before the plugin `add_meta_boxes` is called. I just don't know if this will affect posts that already have that value set.

```
function set_robotsmeta_default() {
    global $post;
    if (!isset($post->robotsmeta) || $post->robotsmeta == "") {
        $post->robotsmeta = "noindex,nofollow";
    }  
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'set_robotsmeta_default', 1);
```

Comment: I tried adding that to my functions file with no luck. Should I try it someplace else?

Comment: You got it. The updated code is good to go. I'm not worried about existing posts, what you wrote is perfect. Thank you very much!